# How to have Jenkins ignore certain files when checking for change?

Tags: regex, jenkins, hudson, cvs

In the "Excluded Regions" of the CVS configuration, I have added the following:

```
.*/.*/.*\.d
.*/.*/.*\.o
.*/.*/.*\.so
.*/.*/.*\.a
.*/.*/.*\.exe
.*/.*/.*\.obj
.*/.*/.*\.dll
.*/.*/.*\.lib
.*/.*/.*\.txt
.*/.*/.*\.tar
.*/.*/.*\.tar\.gz
```

All files with the above extensions should be ignored. However, Jenkins still runs builds based on the fact that a file "build.txt" in some folder ABC has changed, or the one of the tar.gz files has changed. How to get Jenkins to ignore these files? Is something wrong with my regex?

Comment: My guess is it has to do with the `.*/` parts. Have you tried it with just `.*\.txt`?

Comment: Checking now; one of my projects should be checking for changes in about 5 minutes..

Comment: That worked! Can you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad that worked for you! Reposting as requested:

> My guess is it has to do with the `.*/` parts. Have you tried it with just `.*\.txt`?

Just as an experiment, you might also try `/.*/.*/.*\.txt` (note the extra `/` at the beginning). I have a feeling the problem was related to using relative vs. absolute file paths.