# Triggering Jenkins job on changes only in specific folder in CVS job

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have project like this:

```
project/test1 (folder)
project/test2 (folder)
project/test3 (folder)
project/abc.java (file)
```

test1 folder contains files with .java extension and subfolders with more .java files.

I want to trigger build only when files and folders in test1 folder are committed/changed

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the Exclude Regions pattern in the advanced options?

[image]

Maybe you can exclude the test2 and test3 folders and the abc.java file.

Comment: There are many files and folders in the project. I only want to trigger when files in test1 folder are changed. Is there an option of include region? Or can we write pattern in exclude regions to select all folders except the test1 folder?

Comment: Did you have a look to this answer?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215276/how-to-have-jenkins-ignore-certain-files-when-checking-for-change

Comment: Solved. created a new project and gave Modules 'Remote Name' 'project/test1'. Checked 'Poll SCM' to check every minute if there is any update in this folder. Added post-build action to build other projects whenever there is a change in this project and entered the name of my main project.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to do this from within Jenkins.

You will have to do this from your build script or your version server hooks.

We trigger builds from svn, and we want to run different builds depending on the branch on which the commit has been made.

We have hooks that run Powershell scripts looking like this:

```
param(
    [string]$repos,
    [string]$rev
)

$commitTrunk = $false
(Invoke-Expression "svnlook dirs-changed -r $rev `"$repos`"") | % {
    if ($_ -match "^trunk") { $commitTrunk = $true }
}

if ($commitTrunk) {
    $url = "http://myserver/job/Application/build?token=mytoken&cause=SVN+Commit"
    $page = (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
    write $page
}
```

The `svnlook` stuff checks the URL of the current commit to see if it's the trunk. If it is, it triggers the build by calling the Jenkins job URL.

You can do something similar, checking if the path is `project/test1`.
I think Git also has an equivalent to the svn "hook" system.